# Can we do Sandhyavandanam without taking bath?

Tags: vedas, advaita, vaishnavism, sandhyavandanam, smarta

Can we do Sandhyavandanam without taking bath? Is there some restrictions before doing Sandhyavandanam?

Comment: Bath is a must .... But i think if bath is not possible during extreme circumstances panchasuddhi can do to(washing hands,feet,face and rinse mouth)

Comment: Is panchashuddhi an alternative to bathing? @Rāmachandra

Comment: @Das No **only** for sp cases....